# Ros2 packages waits indefinitely after run- windows10

Tags: c++, windows-10, ros2

I have installed ros2 foxy on my windows 10 machine. I was able to run example nodes in the tutorial initially but now its indefinitely waiting after the ros2 run command is issued. I tried reinstalling ros2 multiple times but it didn't help. I followed the instructions mentioned [here](https://ms-iot.github.io/ROSOnWindows/GettingStarted/SetupRos2.html) to install ROS2 Foxy. Is there any way that i can completely remove ros along with all dependencies?
Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have trouble uninstalling Visual Studio (required for ROS as per docs)?

Comment: There were no issues while uninstalling  VS

Comment: I think for removing ROS, you need to follow the reverse steps. If you installed something using the package manager, uninstall it using the same, and so on.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: What is the issue you see after removing?

Comment: It doesn't show errors while removing. But when i reinstall ROS and try to run a ros package, it won't run.

Comment: Please elaborate, what do you mean by won't run?

Comment: Hi, I encountered the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04. Could you find a solution or understand the issue?